# CPU credits on AWS EC2 instance how does that work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a micro amazon EC2 instance, and whenever the hosted application at this platform is given a large load for a couple of hours, the application slows down and CPU credits reach almost to zero.

I have turned auto scaling option on but still it does not work can some help me to figure out how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All t2 instances use a burstable model. Which is not really intended for sustained heavy usage. The instance, when idling, will build up CPU credits up to a cap. When the CPU is maxed, the credits are spent. Once you run out, you are capped at a very low rate. The amount of credits you can get and the rate at which you earn them depend on which t2 instance you are using.

Autoscaling is for horizontal scaling. With it you can launch extra instances based on certain triggers. But you need to use a load balancer to spread traffic accross instances.

Comment: Do you know how auto-scaling policies work with the "burstable" performance model?

For example, say I run out of credits, so my CPU performance is capped at 20%, but I have an auto-scaling trigger to add instances if CPU is above 75%, will this trigger ever get invoked?

If not, is it preferable to use other types of metrics for auto-scaling on burstable instances, such as RequestCount or NetworkOut?

Comment: I am not entirely sure it would. It uses numbers reported to Cloudwatch. I'm not entirely certain what happens when the instance runs out of credits. It may report 100% CPU since its using everything thats allotted. If you are looking at needing autoscale, you probably want to start with larger non-burstable instances anyway.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the insight.  Do you know of any good references on selecting instance types, or more specifically, why a non-burstable instance might be preferred in an Auto-Scaling (e.g. Elastic Beanstalk) environment?

Comment: There are no good rules. Every application is different. Some need more CPU, others need more memory. Some are best with a balance of the two. You will need to test your application to figure out which instance provides the best performance to cost ratio.

Answer (score 0):

To the question how you see on the CPU utilization if you are using all your credited CPU at 100%, my experience is you don't. What you see is in top or iostat for exmaple, your CPU% is reported at something quite low. Like 30%, while IO is not bottlenecked, and you wonder why it is stuck to low CPU% usage.

But there is a value you might see in top, at the far right end, something like "68% st" that is the "steal" value. This means that you only get to have 32% of that CPU, and so your 30% CPU value is actually 94% of what you get.

I have also observed that when you add the CPU% of the processes that are in running state (R) in top, you arrive at a number relative to your actually available CPU. For example, I had 24 processes running at 8% each on a t2.medium instance with 2 virtual CPUs, that means 192% actually running, that is 96% of the available CPU cycles, not 32% as reported by top and iostat as % user.

If I was to generate an auto scale trigger, I would look at what I can get from the /proc file system and consider the "steal" amount.